# compare edited and unsaved with saved version of file in vi

Tags: vim, vi

is there any way I can know all changes I made to a (existing) file before saving it in vi ?
In other words any way to do "diff" between saved and edited version of a file in vi.
Thanks

Comment: I use vi and vim both.Added vim tag

Comment: If you're stuck wondering why a buffer is marked as edited and don't want to lose the changes, you can always use `:w new_file_name` and then use plain old diff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim` defines a `:DiffOrig` command that does exactly that. See also `:help :DiffOrig` for the description. Just copy the command definition to your `~/.vimrc`, and you're done!